# compare value from two files and print out match values

Tags: python, numpy, vcf-variant-call-format

I have two files, a text file, and a vcf file.  I want to look up values of the text file on the vcf file. if there is a match I want to print out the match value but I get the error:  ix = allel.SortedIndex(allel['POS']).locate_intersection(callset["variants/POS"])
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

the content of the files look like this

```
#CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO
 1 10366 rs58108140 G A 100 PASS AN=2184;AC=314
 1 10611 rs189107123 C G 100 PASS AC=41;AN=2184
 1 13302 rs180734498 C T 100 PASS AN=2184;AC=249
 1 13327 rs144762171 G C 100 PASS AC=59;AN=2184
```

```
def readVcf():
    allel.vcf_to_zarr("merged_Small.vcf", "example.zarr", fields="*", overwrite=True)
    callset = zarr.open_group('example.zarr', mode="r")
    file2=allel.vcf_to_recarray("FamilyVarient.txt")

    ix = file2.SortedIndex(file2['POS']).locate_intersection(callset["variants/POS"])
    print(ix)
```

Comment: Hello! What is `allel`?

Comment: http://alimanfoo.github.io/2017/06/14/read-vcf.html

Comment: in your code it says SortedIndex(file2['POS']) but in the error you have SortedIndex(allel['POS']), are you sure the code you posted is correct?